# How to retrieve strings from database containing forward slash using mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with a field containing a string and a forward slash in it (ie. "`some string / with a slash in it`"). At the moment of executing a query and extracting the row, the forward slash seems to be gone. Why is this? and How can I get that slash in the query?

I looked around and all I could find was this `mysql_real_escape_string()` function. But I believe this is for inserting not extracting.

PD: I have the feeling that no forward slash is allowed in databases for some reason. Why?

Thank you

Comment: Must be something in php or your code. The database itself definitely allows a `/` in the data.

Comment: It seems more likely that you failed to insert the string with a slash than that you cannot extract it with one.

Answer (score 1):

you might have a `stripslashes()` call on the string before inserting or after retriving the record

Comment: Thank you guys. I figured it out. I had the code 'if( isset( $data['description'] ) ) $this->description = preg_replace ("/[^\.\,\-\_\'\"\@\?\!\:\$ a-zA-Z0-9()]/","", $data['description'] );' when writing the constructor for the class which was escaping the forward slashes.